# calculating radius of convergence of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1+x^k}{1+y^k}z^k$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I want to calculate the radius of convergence of $$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac1{k!}z^{k^2} \qquad\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1+x^k}{1+y^k}z^k$$with $z\in\mathbb C$ and $x,y\in\mathbb R^+$

For the first one: Let $$a_n:=\begin{cases}0&\textrm{if }n\neq k^2 \\
\frac1{k!}&\textrm{else}\end{cases}$$

Then $$\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\sqrt[k^2]{\frac{1}{k!}}=\sqrt[k]{\sqrt[k]{\frac1{k!}}}$$

Why is the limit $1$?

For the second I guess $\lim_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{1+x^k}{1+y^k}}= \frac xy$
I think I have to use the squeeze theorem but I have idea how.

How can you get those two limits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

For the second series discuss the different cases: $x,y>1$ and $x=1,y>1$ and $x<1,y>1$ and $x>1, y=1$ etc

For the first series you can use the ratio test which fits better with the factorial.

**Added:** For the second series let's show the case $x>1,y<1$: we have
$$\left(\frac{1+x^k}{1+y^k}\right)^{1/k}\sim_\infty \left(\frac{x^k}{1}\right)^{1/k}=x$$
hence the radius is $$R=\frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: for the first one: $\frac{|z|^{(k+1)^2}k!}{|z|^{k^2}(k+1)!} =\frac{|z|^{2k+1}}{k+1}$ and so it converges for $|z|<1$ and diverges for $|z|>1$ and for $|z|=1$ it depends on $z$... right? and could you expand your hint for the second sum? I see the cases $x=1$ or $y=1$ but the other not. thanks.

Comment: @Peter I edited my answer.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: Again my lovely codes $\sim_{\infty}$

Answer (score 0):

For the second one: First notice for $x,y\in\mathbb R^+$ we have $$\sqrt[n]{x^n+y^n}\xrightarrow[]{n\to\infty}\max\{x,y\}$$ 
since for $x\geq y$ we have $$ x=\sqrt[n]{x^n}\leq \sqrt[n]{x^n+y^n}=x\cdot\sqrt[]{1+\Bigl(\frac{y}{x}\Bigr)^n}\leq\sqrt[n]2
\cdot x$$

So for $x,y\geq1$ we get
$$
\sqrt[n]{\frac{1+x^n}{1+y^n}}=\frac{\sqrt[n]{1+x^n}}{\sqrt[n]{1+y^n}}\xrightarrow[]{n\to\infty}\frac xy
$$
and therefore $R=\frac yx$.

Doing the same for $x,y\leq 1$ we get $R=1$ and for $x\geq1$, $y\leq1$ we get $R=\frac1x$ and for $y\geq1$, $x\leq1$ we get $R=y$.